# A text to be displayed in various part of Body

Tags: javascript, html, head

I want one or more text-lines to be written at one place and it should be appear wherever called through out the body. I have written the following code in the head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfucn(){
        document.write("Hello World");
        document.write(" <a href="www.google.com">google</a> ");
    }
</script>
```

I want these two line should be placed through out the body where ever I call the myfunc() or through any other way. If you have any other type of solutions to do so without external javascript file please mention. Also please mention what should I write(at the body) where I am calling the function/js.

Comment: Along with plain text I want also some html tags/texts. like links etc..

Comment: not here Munna..update your question

Answer (score 0):

This would be useful

Include this in the `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    window.myfucn = function() {
            var html = "Hello World";
            html += '<a href="www.google.com">google</a>';
            // keep adding your elements to html
           document.write(html);
    }

</script>
```

Now you can call it easily like this:

```
<p><script type="text/javascript">myfucn();</script></p>
```

Comment: Ok, inside body tag <body> what should I write to call that function?

Comment: Thaks a lot! Let me try this out!

Comment: Do you know any other site where I could store my javascript file and edit that time to time too without changing the url of file..

Comment: You can store it in Google Drive http://www.techsperia.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-to-host-javascript-and-css-scripts.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as @mohamedrias said. To implement it, you'll need to do the following wherever you want it to appear:

```
<div>
    <script> myfucn() </script>
</div>
```

Just call the function and it will put those two lines into the parent container of the `<script>` element.